# Trying to install glassfish-3 for Java EE 6 tutorial examples

Tags: java-ee-6, glassfish-3, netbeans-8

I am trying to install glassfish-3 with NetBean. The tutorial page below asks me to install Java EE 6 SDK first, which I did.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gexaj.html

But I am unable to find the location of Java EE 6 on my PC. Any idea how I might find it?

Answer (score 1):

Download Glassfish from here https://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1.2.2-final.html
download a version of choice , on Netbeans , under Services, right click server, and add server,choose glassfish and select install location,admin ports and http port. jee6 comes shipped in Glassfish module if you are using an ANT project. I will advice you use maven project , add this your dependency pom as this using maven allows you to use specific jee dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```